# Regex - Find matches with the same characters at specific positions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of 8-letter sequences like this:

```
    ['GQPLWLEH', 'TLYSFFPK', 'TYGEIFEK', 'APYWLINK', ...]
```

How can I use regular expressions to find all the sequences that have the specific letters at specific positions within the sequence? For example, the letters V, I, F, or Y at the 2nd letter in the sequence and the letters M, L, F, Y at the 3rd position in the sequence.

I'm really new to RE, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following regex pattern:

```
.[VIFY][MLFY].*
```

This will match any first character, followed by a second and third character using the logic you want.

```
import re
mylist = ['GQPLWLEH', 'TLYSFFPK', 'TYGEIFEK', 'APYWLINK']
r = re.compile(".[VIFY][MLFY].*")
newlist = filter(r.match, mylist)
print str(newlist)
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Note: I added the word `BILL` to your list in the demo to get something which passes the regex match.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b.[VIFY][MLFY]\w*\b
```

This may satisfy what you want. You can play with regex online at [regex101](https://regex101.com)

[image]

Comment: The explanation dump from Regex101 does not help your answer much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid using a regexp altogether:

`[x for x in mylist if x[1] in 'VIFY' and x[2] in 'MLFY']`